# Improve performance on retrieving class Record Association attribute values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to improve the following code:

```
@user.article_relationships.select(:category_id).map(&:category_id)
```

Where:

- `@user` is an instance of a User class
- `article_relationships` is the method "gained" by an User Active Record Association with the Article class
- `:category_id` is an attribute of each `article_relationships` (that is, a database table column of `article_relationships`)

The output of the above code is something like this:

```
# Those are all 'category_id' values present in the 'article_relationships' array
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

**There is a way to improve that code for *performance purposes*** (mostly for the `select(:category_id).map(&:category_id)` part)**?** That is, there is a "direct" way to retrieve `category_id` data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word... no. There's not a more "direct" way to access the category_ids. Some notes though:

- You don't have to do `.select(:category_id)`. Unless article records contain lots of data, the performance increase would be negligible. `@user.article_relationships.map(&:category_id)` should do.
- More than anything, the largest performance boost you could get here is by indexing the `user_id` column in the articles table. This can easily be done in a migration: `add_index :articles, :user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eager loading using `include` when finding @user's object

or directly skip `select`

@user.article_relationships.map(&:category_id)

Comment: The 'select' is usefull to performance: it make possible to load less data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

As the other person answered, there's no direct or recommended way to do this.

The main tip is not to loop through the results twice, map() loops through every result and calls .company_id, if you're going to loop through the results again then leave the .map off and call .company_id yourself when you need it.